# Can WIndows Virtual PC run both XP-Mode and other VHDs?

Tags: windows-virtual-pc

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate, and I'd like to use Windows Virtual PC to run both XP-Mode and other VHDs I've created.  Is it possible to do both?

Comment: Which version of Virtual PC?

Comment: Windows Virtual PC is the version.  http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/

Comment: Microsoft have released a number of version. They all have the same name but do not all have the same capabilities.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? If so, awarding the answer and an upvote would be helpful to future readers. Or you can enter your own answer as well if it was different.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/), the next version above Microsoft Virtual PC 2007, [supports other Windows operating systems besides XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958559). One can extrapolate that other operating systems could be ran under Microsoft Virtual PC, but they wouldn't be "supported". Some information about the support and performance of Linux in Microsoft Virtual PC is included in the [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is not reason to not.